# Duplex communication with a file representing serial port (com) in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a gadget connected via USB and showing itself on a COM port when connected (on Windows). I can access the port like this and write and read in sequence:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.open('\\\\.\\COM3', 'w+', function (error, fd) {
    var data = new Buffer('some command\r\n', 'ascii');
    fs.write(fd, data, 0, data.length, null, function (error) {
        var data = new Buffer(1);
        fs.read(fd, data, 0, 1, null, function (error) {
            // process char from data[0] and check whether we should read more
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, however, that when I want to read more bytes than available, the fs.read is pending and fs.write does not work.

In addition, I do not know whether there are any data waiting when the device is connected and I would like to read them before sending any commands (otherwise I do not know whether the data read is a response or just unread data before sending a command).

**Solution candidate #1:** Find a way to detect whether there are data available for reading. That would also mean a very complicated logic of retries and polling using timeouts... I have not seen such function for a file descriptor in node anyway.

**Solution candidate #2:** Use a read function with a timeout and do not write while one is pending until it has timed out. Or at least cancel reading when proceeding with write...

**Solution candidate #3:** Use the new stream API, especially the Duplex stream... however I am unable to do so for a file (or a file descriptor)

I know that native functions do have these features, so I may have missed some "hidden" API, or it had not been exposed in node.js yet...

There are some solutions for serial port communication that use native extensions to node. I cannot use those for various reasons. Moreover, what I have in plain node mostly works...

The question is, of course, is what I am trying to do even possible in the current node.js version and if, what would be the best way.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport ?

Comment: @vkurchatkin Mentioned that in the second last paragraph. The thing with node-serialport is that it is a C++ module requiring VS2013 and python for installation... that is unacceptable in my case.